# Reading and Writing Huge Files C++(Memory Overload)

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have a very huge file(55 gigabytes of json data). I am using `ifstream` to read and another `ofstream` to write to another file. The program runs correctly for some time. And then crashes due to heavy memory usage.

I tried using `ignore` and `clear` to clear the input buffer.
And also tried using `flush` to clear the output buffer.

Also the file is very huge, So, I want it to be fast.

p.s. I wrote the json parser while half asleep. So please pardon my bad parser code. And maybe the memory leak is present there. Any help will be appreciated.

Small Example

```
int main() 
{ 
    std::ifstream file("aggressive_dedup.json", std::ifstream::in);
    std::ofstream outFile("processed.json", std::ofstream::out);
    std::string str;
    int a; 
    long long count = 0;


    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {

        JsonParserStateMachine jsonParserStateMachine;
        for(char &c : str) jsonParserStateMachine.changeState(c);
        //std::cout<<jsonParserStateMachine.getReview();
        //This lines just gives a string to the output which is around may be 1000 characters 
        outFile << jsonParserStateMachine.getReview(); 
        if(++count % 1000 == 0) {
            std::cout<<count<<" Processed\n";
            outFile.flush();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For those who are willing to see the whole code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum state {
    q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, h
};

class KeyValueStore{
    std::string *keys;
    std::string *values;
    int currentKeyPosition;
    int currentValuePosition;
    int maxLength;
public:
    KeyValueStore(const int length) : maxLength(length),currentKeyPosition(0),currentValuePosition(0)
    {
        this->keys = new std::string[length];
        this->values = new std::string[length];

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            this->keys[i] = "";
            this->values[i] = "";
        }

    }

    void updateKeyPosition()
    {
        this->currentKeyPosition = this->currentKeyPosition++%9;
    }
    void updateValuePosition()
    {
        this->currentValuePosition = this->currentValuePosition++%9;
    }

    void putKey(char c)
    {
        this->keys[currentKeyPosition] += c;
    }
    void putValue(char c)
    {
        this->values[currentValuePosition] += c;
    }


    std::string getValue(std::string key)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<this->maxLength;i++)
        {
            if(this->keys[i] == key) return this->values[i];
        }
        return "";
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Keys"<<"\t"<<"Values"<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<maxLength;i++)
        {
            std::cout<<this->keys[i] <<'\t'<<this->values[i]<<std::endl;
        }
    }


    std::string getReview()
    {
        return std::string("{\"" +  this->getValue("reviewText") + "\":\"" + this->getValue("overall") + "\"}"); 
    }
};



class JsonParserStateMachine{
    state currentState;
    KeyValueStore keyValueStore;
    bool inNum;
    bool inArray;
public:
    JsonParserStateMachine(): keyValueStore(9), currentState(state::q0), inNum(false),inArray(false){}

    state getState()
    {
        return this->currentState;
    }

    void print()
    {
        keyValueStore.print();
    }


    std::string getReview()
    {
        return keyValueStore.getReview();
    }

    state changeState(char c)
    {
        switch(currentState)
        {
            case state::q0:
                if(c == ' ') break;
                else if(c == '{') this->currentState = state::q1;
                else this->currentState = state::h;
                break;
            case state::q1:
                if(c == ' ') break;
                else if(c == '\"') this->currentState = state::q2;
                else this->currentState = state::h;
                break;
            case state::q2:
                if(c == '\"'){
                    this->currentState = state::q3;
                    this->keyValueStore.updateKeyPosition();
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    this->keyValueStore.putKey(c);
                    break;
                } 
            case state::q3:
                if(c == ':') this->currentState = state::q4;
                else if(c == ' ') {

                }
                else {
                    //std::cout<<"From Q3"<<std::endl;
                    this->currentState = state::h;
                }break;
            case state::q4:
                if(c == '\"' || c == '[') {
                    this->currentState = state::q5;
                    inArray = c == '[' ? true: false; 

                }else if(c == ' ') break;
                else {
                    //std::cout<<"Got Here"<<std::endl;
                    inNum = true;
                    this->currentState = state::q5;
                    this->keyValueStore.putValue(c);
                }
                break;
            case state::q5:
                if(c == '\"' || c == ']'){
                    this->currentState = state::q6;
                    this->keyValueStore.updateValuePosition();
                    inArray = c == ']'? false: true;
                    break;
                }else if(inNum && c == ',' ){
                    this->currentState = state::q1;
                    this->keyValueStore.updateValuePosition();
                    inNum = false;
                }
                else{
                    this->keyValueStore.putValue(c);
                    break;
                } 
            case state::q6:
                if(c == ','){
                    this->currentState = state::q1;
                    break;
                }else if(c == ' '){
                    break;
                }else{
                    //std::cout<<"From Q6"<<std::endl;
                    this->currentState = state::h;
                }
        }

        return this->currentState;
    }
};

class Review{

    std::string reviewText;
    int overall;
    std::string summary;
public:
    void pusReviewText(std::string reviewText)
    {
        this->reviewText = reviewText;
    }

    void putOverall(int overall)
    {
        this->overall = overall;
    }


    void putSummary(std::string summary)
    {
        this->summary = summary;
    }

    std::string getReviewText()
    {
        return this->reviewText;
    }
    int getOverall()
    {
        return this->overall;
    }
    std::string getSummary()
    {
        return this->summary;
    }
};

int main() 
{ 
    std::ifstream file("aggressive_dedup.json", std::ifstream::in);
    std::ofstream outFile("processed.json", std::ofstream::out);
    std::string str;
    int a; 
    long long count = 0;


    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {

        JsonParserStateMachine jsonParserStateMachine;
        for(char &c : str) jsonParserStateMachine.changeState(c);
        //std::cout<<jsonParserStateMachine.getReview();
        outFile << jsonParserStateMachine.getReview();
        if(++count % 1000 == 0) {
            std::cout<<count<<" Processed\n";
            outFile.flush();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i also searched stackoverflow, and all questions were suggesting flush, and ignore

Comment: Your `KeyValueStore` needs a destructor.

Comment: @Frank let me try that now..

Comment: I just converted my project to VS. to take a snapshot. Maybe that will help too

Comment: Besides, you're looking for trouble with `this->currentKeyPosition = this->currentKeyPosition++%9;`

Comment: This is probably not related to ifstream. I don't see KeyValueStore ever clearing up strings store in its vectors, so every putKey/putValue call increases memory pressure without ever relieving it. But performance-wise: for this sequencial read pattern you might want to retire std::getline and use block read (istream::read into some buffer) instead. Was a huge speed bonus for me in similar task. Or even drop ifstream entirely and mmap your input file few megs at a time, and read directly from a mmap.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin No reason to mmap only a few megs at a time – mmap the whole file at once (on 64bits at least). There’s enough virtual memory for everyone. Let the OS handle eviction of the pages itself.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin how much was the scale for the read speed.

Comment: It might help as an optimization; remove your variable declaration for your `JsonParserStateMachine` outside the `while loop` inside your main. Do you really need to declare it; use it, destroy it on each iteration of your while loop? You can declare it once above the while loop, then just use it within on each iteration. That would save you a good amount of computation.

Comment: @FrancisCugler i needed to make an extra function to reset it. And i thought it will be almost same as making a new one.. will profile to check it.

Comment: @KishanKumar yeah; just something to think about.

Comment: @JonasWielicki true, on 64bits it would probably fit in VM. Though there's no need to since access pattern is known in advance (but then no reason not to).

Comment: @KishanKumar for me it was 3x improvement on overall execution time (using vs2013 and in-memory files). You just need to add \n handling and then you can get rid of getline logic, buffering, std::string population etc - a whole lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @Andrew Turkin will add that method now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your `KeyValueStore` class:

```
KeyValueStore(const int length) : maxLength(length),currentKeyPosition(0),currentValuePosition(0)
{
    this->keys = new std::string[length];
    this->values = new std::string[length];
    ...
```

Nothing ever deletes these arrays. Deleting them in a destructor is the simple fix:

```
~KeyValueStore() {
  delete[] this->keys;
  delete[] this->values;
}
```

However! You really should consider using `std::vector<std::string>` instead. Or even better, rebuild the entire thing around a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> instead.`

Comment: i am not planning to use STL

Comment: Then why are you using fstreams? Many parts of the STL can be problematic, but there is no possible valid reason to avoid using std::vector if fstreams are fair game. Heck, std::string is easily the most objectionable part, and you are using them a lot.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Frank; using `std::map` for a `key, value` pair is excellent if you are concerned with fast search time for an entry via a key object, otherwise if you are not concerned about traversing over the set of strings, then `std::vector` would work just as good. `std::map` when sorted is `log(2)` where `std::vector` is linear in their worst case scenarios for traversing across the data structures.